# How do I filter on bold, struck through or italic text in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting

Is it possible to filter an Excel column based on the format of the text, such as whether it's bold, italic or struck through?

Comment: [Macro solution](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/913-excel-filter-bold-cells.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly - you can only filter an Excel column based on its value, its cell colour, or its font colour.

However, using Find and Replace, you can replace all formatting of a certain type with a filterable version: e.g. replacing all struck through cells with cells with red text. You can then filter on this basis.

Comment: Also you can achieve it by using Excel macros (VBA)

Comment: @Searas - Absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Module solution for italics (adapted from [here](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/913-excel-filter-bold-cells.html))

```
Function IsItalics(rCell As Range)
IsItalics = rCell.Font.Italic
End Function
```

Then, IsItalics(cell address)